# apollo client- [Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400]

Tags: react-native, apollo-client

The application uses apollo server and react Native in the frontend. In the backend I use apollo server. The request works via the Playground and I don't get any errors. Queries in the frontend without parameters also work perfectly. When I make a mutation in the frontend, I get the following error error: Response not successful: Received status code 400.

src/queries/queries.js

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";
export const SIGNUP_USERS = gql`
mutation createUser($newUser:UserInput!) {
  CreateUser(newUser:$newUser){
    firstName
  }
}

src/components/Signup.js

import { useMutation } from '@apollo/client'
import { SIGNUP_USERS } from '../gqloperations/Mutation'


const Signup = () => {

    const [formData,setFormData] = useState({firstName:'',LastName:'',email:'',password:''})
     const [signupUser,{data,loading,error}]  =  useMutation(SIGNUP_USERS)

     if(loading) return  <Text>Loading... </Text>
     if(error) return console.log("error is=====>",error)

    const handleChange = (name,value) => {
       setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [name] : value
       })
    }


    const handleSubmit = () => {
         console.log("signup data is",formData)
         signupUser({
          variables:{
            newUser:formData
          }
         })
    }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
      <View style={styles.innerView}>
         <View style={styles.titleView} >
           <Text style={styles.title}>Signup</Text>
         </View>
         { error && <View> <Text style={{color:'red'}}>{error.message}</Text></View> }
         {  data && data.user && <View><Text style={{color:'green'}}>{data.firstName} Signup sucessfully!</Text>         </View>  }
         <View style={{height:hp('5%')}}></View>
         <View style={styles.textInputView}>
           <TextInput placeholder='Please Enter FirstName' style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('firstName',text)} value={formData.firstName}    
      />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.textInputView}>
           <TextInput  placeholder='Please Enter LastName'  style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('LastName',text)} value={formData.LastName} />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.textInputView}>
           <TextInput  placeholder='Please Enter Email'  style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('email',text)} value={formData.email} />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.textInputView}>
           <TextInput secureTextEntry={true} placeholder='Please password'  style={styles.textInput} onChangeText={(text) => handleChange('password',text)} value={formData.password}/>
         </View>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonView} onPress={handleSubmit} >
           <Text style={styles.btnText}>Signup</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

A 400 error from a GraphQL server is *almost always* an invalid query or mutation.

Your mutation:

```
mutation createUser($newUser:UserInput!) {
  CreateUser(newUser:$newUser){
    firstName
  }
}
```

looks fine. Odds are that `formData` does not have the same shape as `UserInput`

```
variables:{ newUser:formData }
```

Possible issues:

- missing a required key
- has an unexpected key
- has an invalid value for a key

Attempt the mutation from the playground first to troubleshoot.

Comment: What was the problem?